# Hudson - different build targets for different triggers

Tags: build, hudson, maven

I would like to have different build targets for periodic builds and for those that are triggered by polling SCM.

More specific: The idea is that nightly builds should call 'mvn verify' which includes integration tests, while a normal build calls 'mvn test' that just executes Unit tests.

Any ideas how this can be achieved using Hudson?

Cheers
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create two jobs - one scheduled and the other polled.
In the scheduled you can specify a different maven goal from the polled.

Comment: that's the obvious solution :)
Thanks. I just thought that maybe one could distinguish different build targets within the same job.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Raghuram is straight forward and correct. But you can also have three jobs. The first two do the triggering and pass the maven goal as a parameter into the third job. Sounds like a lot of clutter, and to a certain point it is. But it will help, if you have a lot of configuration to do (especially if the configuration needs to be changed regularly). It will help to have the configuration correct for both jobs. Configuration does not only include the build steps but also the harvesting of all reports, post build cleanup, notifications, triggering of downstream jobs, ... Another advantage is, that you don't need to synchronize the two jobs, so that they not run in parallel (if that causes problems).

Don't understand me wrong, my first impulse would go for two jobs, which has it's own advantages. The history for the nightly build will be contain the whole day (actually since the last nightly build) and not only for the time since the last build (which could be a triggered one. Integration tests usually need a more extensive setup or access to scarce resources. With two jobs you don't block these resources when you run the test goal. In addition I expect that more test results need to be harvested to be displayed and tracked over time by Hudson. You also might want to run more metrics against your code whose results should be displayed by Hudson. The disadvantage is that you of course need to keep the build steps basically the same all the time.

**But in the end it is a case-by base decision if you go with  2  or 3 jobs.**