# Hudson project with multiple triggers

Tags: build, continuous-integration, hudson

I am building a continuous integration system with Hudson, and have a project split into two parts. The first is the main build and unit test element, which I want to run in the traditional CI fashion, triggered off SVN. The second is the functional tests, which take a long time to run, and so I want them to run overnight.

Is there any way of setting up a Hudson project with multiple triggers, i.e. so the functional tests run each night if and only if the main project has changed and has built successfully.

I've seen this question: [Hudson - different build targets for different triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488312/hudson-different-build-targets-for-different-triggers), but that simply runs each night regardless of the state of the main project.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same situation that you do: a build with some quick sanity tests tied to SVN, but a nightly regression test that takes longer.

Our solution was to use the [DOS Build Trigger Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/DOS+Trigger).  On that build trigger, we attach a schedule that triggers once a night.  The Trigger Script is a series of simple commands like this:

```
set CAUSE=
curl  http://localhost:8080/job/THEBUILDJOB/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/fingerprint.txt -o current.txt
if not exist current.txt exit 0
fc /B current.txt last.txt
if ERRORLEVEL 1 set CAUSE=New build available
copy /y current.txt last.txt
```

This gets a particular file (fingerprint.txt) from the last successful build and compares it (via fc) to a copy we've stored in the workspace.  If they match - no build occurs.  If they're different, we trigger a build via the DOS Build Trigger by setting the CAUSE variable, then store the new file in the trigger's workspace.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like that plug-in doesn't support custom workspaces, which I'm using to store the binaries from the build task so that the tests can access them. Presumably it needs to be running on a Windows server in order to run DOS scripts as well?

Comment: I'm not sure about the Windows-only part, but I'm sort of guessing that based on the name of the plugin.  And yes, custom workspaces would be an issue.  You could probably use hard-coded paths instead of the workspace relative ones.